# Clean install flickering

Tags: 20.04

I've uploaded a video here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKnLq.jpg

After a clean install my screen flickers. When I installed 20.04 after it's release it was totally fine. I tried Pop_OS! for a while, then went to Kubuntu. But now want to go back to Ubuntu.

So I created a new USB stick, unplugged all my HDD's except for 1 NVME, and ran the install.

- 1st attempt: Installed fine, stuck at boot, reboot, stuck at boot.
- 2nd attempt: Installed fine, booted, screen flickering. Tried updating everything. Still flickering. Tried installing AMD's drivers which seem to fail every attempt.

Then tried Mint and Kubuntu: 0 issues, no screen flickering.

- 3rd attempt: Installed fine, stuck at boot, rebooted, screen flickering.

Then I disabled 1 monitor and re-enabled it and the flickering stopped. Rebooting, it comes back.

I tried setting the screen tearing setting but that didn't help.

Then saw someone posted on here saying they installed and didn't tick to include third party drivers.

- 4th attempt: Installed without third party drivers, booted, screen flickering.

I've never experienced screen flickering before so I'm lost to figure this out and every search usually comes to screen tearing not flickering.

Edit: I don't believe this is hardware related as it doesn't do this on other distros or windows 10.